# Get parent div id name when inner div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to find a way to get the name of the parent ID in a string. The code is part of a chat app written in Javascript and jQuery.  Each time someone enters a message, the string outputs a block with username and text with a Close-x box before the username.  When someone clicks the Close-x, it needs to grab the ID name of the parent div(json.innerdiv). The div with ID named json.outterdiv is the ID which allows me to delete the whole block message where as the json.innerdiv allows me to remove text, change text or just hide/show text. I tried searching on here for answers but all I ever get is undefined or null results.

My code:

```
var bubble = $('<div class="bubble-container" id="'+json.outterdiv+'"><span class="bubble"><div class="bubble-text" id="'+json.innerdiv+'"><p><div class="close-x" onclick="DelBubble(this)"></div>Some text</p></div></div>');

function DelBubble(clicked_id) {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `event` to `onclick` then get the `closest` of a `class` selector using jquery:

```js
var bubble = `
<div class="bubble-container" id="2">
    <span class="bubble">
       <div class="bubble-text" id="3">
       <p>
       <div class="close-x" onclick="DelBubble(event)">
       Close
       </div>
       Some text
       </p>
       </div>
</div>`;

$('body').append(bubble)

function DelBubble(e) {

const bubbleTextId = $(e.target).closest('.bubble-text').attr('id');

const bubbleContainerId = $(e.target).closest('.bubble-container').attr('id');
console.log({bubbleTextId,bubbleContainerId})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, I think I can work with that, for some reason when comments are added they are not placed in the chat screen but appear at the bottom of my page lol but I am sure I can make the needed changes to correct this.

Comment: I needed to remove  the line $('body').append(bubble) because it kept placing the message block outside of the text screen but all working fine now without that line. Not too sure if it is an important line but works without it none the less. thank you